# How does Subversion detect conflict in files?

Tags: svn

While fetching an update from repository, SVN detects conflict with the local copy of the modified files and those in the server. How does it detect conflict in files? Is it based on comparing same line numbers in both the files? How does the algorithm work?

Answer (score 1):

Like all revision control systems SVN is based on diffs and their application to text based files. So when merging, SVN takes the series of diffs that express what changes should be merged and applies those diffs one at a time. That works fine as long as the diffs *can be applied*. If not, you get a "conflict".

Diffs can not be applied when the text files they are meant to be applied to have been altered, so that the diff does not "fit" any more. This is typically the case when the file has been altered at the same position the diff is meant to be applied to.

In such case SVN (like most revision control systems) cowardly refuses to apply the diff. What SVN sees is this: a line should be altered according to the diff, but it has already been altered to something else by your local files state. So which alteration is meant to be the final one? This is an either/or question that usually cannot be resolved automatically, since it requires knowledge of the purpose of the line. Thus SVN leaves the decision to you.

Comment: I expect SVN conflict resolution works as follows:

1. Compute the diff-1 between the working copy and the SVN revision present in .svn/pristine directory.
2. Compute the diff-2 between the HEAD revision and the SVN revision present in .svn/pristine directory.
3. Apply diff-2 as long as it does not conflict with diff-1, otherwise announce "Conflict"

What do you say?

Comment: In my eyes this description only shift the question towards the "as long as it does not conflict". The real question remains: _when_ does it conflict?

Comment: Yes, the question remains